# How to Find the Range and the set notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For appropriate sets    A    and    B   , determine the range of a function    f    :   A   →   B that assigns

(a) to each integer the sum of that integer and its negative.

(b) to each pair of integers the sum of twice of the ﬁrst integer and three times the second integer.

How do you determine the the range from the information given? From what I understand, the range is what the elements in Set A point to in Set B.

from (a) I see that the range is the function will something like f(a) = a +(-a) but how do I represent that as a set? whats the proper notation?

thanks

Comment: You're onto the answer for part (a), you just need to take it a bit further. The range will be the set of all elements of the form a+(-a). But what is a+(-a)? It can be simplified.

Comment: For (a), the domain is $\mathbb{Z}$, and for (b), the domain is $\mathbb{Z}^2$. In (a), the range is the set $\{x - x : x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$; in (b), the range is the set $\{2x + 3y : x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. This isn't the answer, though; you're expected to find a simpler way to express these range sets. Hint: in (b), let $x = -y$.

Comment: thanks. Although how can you go simpler that {2x+3y:x,y∈ℤ}?

Comment: @user3915992 Try (a) first, and you will see what I mean by simpler.

Comment: so for (a) you can simplify it to {0 : x∈ℤ}? is this what you mean?

Comment: $\{0 : x \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{0\}$ (there is no $x$ term before the colon, so there no longer needs to be a reference to where $x$ lives).

Comment: oohhhhhhh I see Thanks